# При изменении маштаб сайта, появляется старый дизайн

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, битрикс

Есть сайт, достался от прошлого программиста, тот ушел, и возможности спросить про эту проблему нет. Лазал по форумам, подобную проблему не нашел. 
Если смотреть на сайт в 100%, то все хорошо, но если уменьшить масштаб, к примеру, до 90%, то появляется старая верстка. Из-за чего это вообще может быть? Чисто в теории, как такое возможно? Возможно поможет то, что сайт на битриксе. Ссылку на сайт прилагаю. http://dostavka-alendvic.ru/
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: И в теории, и на практике стили выбираются в зависимости от текущего размера сайта, что программист прописал для размеров (`max-width: 2000px`) — то и отображается. А вообще вопрос на Stack Overflow оффтопик

Comment: Мне одному кажется что вопрос ради сео продвижения сайта?

Comment: @Nick не думаю, проблема на том сайте реально существует (ну или по крайней мере существовала на момент написания вопроса), а сео это разве что побочный эффект. Но вопрос всё равно нужно закрыть, потому что ссылки на демонстрацию проблемы всё равно не допускаются правилами сайта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, задача действительно решалась легко. При изменении экрана меньше чем на 1000px, вылазила прошлая версия сайта, которая является еще и мобильной. 
Так что данная проблема решается изменением мобильной версии сайта.